# How do I convert this connection string to use SSPI security?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a connection string that works - here it is:

```
<add name="MyEntities"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
  connectionString="metadata=
  res://*/;
  provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
  provider connection string='
  Data Source=localhost;
  Initial Catalog=MyDb;
  Integrated Security=False;
  User Id=MyDbUser;
  Password=123456;
  MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" />
```

I set up the user like this:

```
USE [master]
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins WHERE name = N'MyDbUser')
    DROP LOGIN [MyDbUser];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [MyDbUser]
    WITH
        PASSWORD=N'123456',
        DEFAULT_DATABASE=[MyDb],
        CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
-- Drop & recreate db-user
USE [MyDb]
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'MyDbUser')
    DROP USER [MyDbUser];
GO
CREATE USER [MyDbUser] FOR LOGIN [MyDbUser]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'MyDbUser'
GO
```

If I change the connection string to use SSPI security, it no longer works. As a SQL noob, I'd appreciate it if someone could offer some advice on what other changes I need to make.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[SSPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/security-support-provider-interface-sspi-) can only be specified when using Windows-authenticated logins.  You have created a SQL Server authenticated login, and are specifying that in the connection string via the `User ID=` and `Password=` keywords. Specifying SSPI as well is causing SQL Server to attempt to authenticate the connecting user via their Windows security token, which is not being passed to SQL Server by the client, since the client is specifying a SQL Server username and password.  In short, you're specifying two authentication methods, where only a single method can be specified.

If you want the connection to use a Windows-authenticated user, [create a login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax) using the `FROM WINDOWS` source.  Assuming you have a Windows user named `DOMAIN\MyUser`, you could accomplish that with the following code:

```sql
USE [master];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\MyUser]
FROM WINDOWS;
```

You'd also need to create a user for the login in the desired database:

```sql
USE [<db_name>];
GO
CREATE USER [MyUser]
FOR LOGIN [DOMAIN\MyUser];
```

Note, no passwords are specified in the above statements because *Windows* is looking after authentication.

Then, you need to make sure the application is running as "DOMAIN\MyUser", and is using the following in the connection string:

```xml
<add name="MyEntities"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
  connectionString="metadata=
  res://*/;
  provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
  provider connection string='
  Data Source=localhost;
  Initial Catalog=MyDb;
  Integrated Security=SSPI;
  MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be a Windows user, not a SQL Server user. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

"Integrated Security - When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication. Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true."